# Need some help getting some stuff off a string

Tags: java, android

I want to get some info out of my string but there's two possible "expressions" for the string. I want to get `"a"` & `"b"` out of the string. This is how they look:

Format one:

```
    http://default.com/default/a/b
```

Format two:

```
    http://default.com/#!default|1|a|b|1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings always looks like this, you could do the following:
Search for the #-char to decide, if you have type 1 or 2.
In case of type 1, split with delimiter '/' and always take the last and the one before. For type 2, also first split with '/' and then, split the last part again with delimiter '|' and take results[2] and results[3].

Comment: Exactly, the simplest soultion. You can also use regex, but that would be more complex.

Comment: how do I check which one it is so I can determine that information

Comment: You can for example use `contains("#!default")` if you can ensure, that this charsequence is only available in type 2 - but be careful, if a and/or b are user-provided input.

Another possibility would be to count the number of / in the strings (e.g. doing the split with '/' first, then decide the type on the length of the resulting array. But again, be careful with user provided input.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to split the string.

1. Split on "default"
2. [Regex Split](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/JavaRegularExpressionSplittext.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this - regular expressions is the most common.

In pseudo code:

```
if the string contains "/#!default" then:
  Use the regular expression ^.*/([^/])/([^/])$
if the string contains "/default" then:
  Use the regular expression ^.*|([^|])|([^|])|1$
Take the 1st and 2nd blocks from the matcher
```